# Setting environment variables as constants in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of environment variables on my server which I get through a simple API call:

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('serverService', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/server/';
      return $resource(base, {}, {
        getConfiguration: {method: 'GET', url: base + 'configuration'}
      });
    }]);
```

I call this in several controllers:

```
var getConfiguration = function() {
  serverService.getConfiguration().$promise.then(function(config) {
    vm.config = config;
  });
};
```

I now need access to environment variables in one of my other factories. I know I could inject `serverService` and make this call yet again within that factory, but this seems like a poor choice.

Since my configuration will never change (configuration only differs by environment [dev, staging, prod]) should I be making this API call once when my app loads and setting the resulting object as a Constant? If so, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd make the service method return the promise, rather than execute an new query, assuming this variable is static. Services are singletons, so it should only make one query. At this point, I'd rename serverService to be something more apt, like ConfigurationService, which would "feel" better to inject everywhere.

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('serverService', ['$http',
    function($resource) {
      var base = '/api/server/';
      //Get data and peel off http request data
      var configPromise = $http.get(base + 'configuration').then(function(response){return response.data});
      return {
              getConfiguration: function(){
                return configPromise
              }
            };
        }
    }]);
```

--

```
var getConfiguration = function() {
  serverService.getConfiguration().then(function(config) {
    vm.config = config;
  });
};
```

**Option 2:**

If you can access the constant server side and inject it there in the lifecycle, you can use `app.constant`. This is a better solution, as introducing another AJAX call in your app bootstrap will just slow down page load that much more. This sort of "round trip" bootstrapping cycle can really start to add up.

```
app.constant('config', ${configVar})
```

Comment: Agree with Option 2.